# In Visual Paradigm, how to have a solid line, rather than a dotted line, towards a class that is created later down the timeline?

Tags: uml, message, sequence-diagram, visual-paradigm

I am creating a sequence diagram and I would like the diagram to appear as follows, where the OnlineCart object is placed downwards on the timeline with a solid arrow going towards it:

[image: a normal sequence diagram where a class placed downwards on the timeline with a solid arrow going towards it]

However, when I try this on visual paradigm, if I use a solid line then the Reservation class appears at the top, and only with a dashed line does it appear where I want it (as shown in the second image). What is the reason for this, and is there any bypass to get a solid line, as that is what is used in my textbook diagrams?

[image: sequence diagram in visual paradigm where a class placed downwards on the timeline has a dotted arrow going towards it]

Comment: A create message is defined as dashed line like in the below picture. The top one is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

P. 720 of UML 2.5 shows the create message:

[image]

As you can see this is a dashed line. Which means your first picture is wrong in this respect and the second one is correct.

---

Many lecture questions I've seen here refer to simply wrong examples from teachers. Sad, but true. Keep it with Gershwin: *It Ain't Necessarily So*

Comment: Exactly ! And P.577 they even write the rule in plain text:  "*An object creation Message (messageSort equals createMessage) has a dashed line with an open arrow head.*"